# Difference Between Call of function block in IEC61131-3

Tags: twincat, st

What the difference between assigning a parameter with `dot` and put as an array to a function block?

here is a simple code as an example.

```
Timer1(IN:=TRUE,PT:=T#2S);
IF Timer1.Q THEN
    i:=i+1;
    Timer1.IN:=FALSE;
END_IF

Timer2(IN:=TRUE,PT:=T#2S);
IF Timer2.Q THEN
    j:=j+1;
    Timer2(IN:=FALSE);
END_IF
```

It expected that `Timer1` be reset by this `Timer1.IN:=FALSE;` assignment but nothing happened, although it shows `FALSE` in the code as a real-time value!

[image]

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem? You're leaving it to us to guess what the problem is. If you want Timer1 to behave the same way as Timer2, you need to do Timer1(IN:=FALSE) instead of Timer1.IN:=FALSE;;

Comment: @Jakob  sorry I'll edit in next few hour..

Comment: @Jakob so why Timer1.IN:=FALSE is wrong?

Comment: Because you are not _calling_ the function-block Timer1 with IN = FALSE. You are only assigning it with IN = FALSE (but without executing it), and in the next cycle you assign it with IN = TRUE again (and then you call it). So you are simply not resetting the function block. Note that you're not calling FUNCTIONS, but FUNCTION BLOCKS. Tc2_Standard.TON is a function block.

Comment: @Jakob what is this notation benefit when it doesn't run the function block and just assign it? it causes lots of problems to programmers for troubleshooting when using it in a huge program.

Comment: @asys in many industrial control schemes you don’t necessarily want to call a FB every time you access and input or output variable.  For example, certain FBs should only run once every PLC scan and in a certain order (like drive axis controls) but you need to access the drive data in many places in the program. 

Also, in your sample code, you have IF Timer1.Q Then which is accessing the output Q, not calling the FB - which is exactly what you want.
Your complaint about troubleshooting and problems is based on not understanding the syntax of the programming language.

Comment: Good question. I also made the same mistake where I assumed the assignment of an input variable would execute the function block. Once you understand it, it makes sense I think. See my answer below for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There are just two characters which make a huge difference between the outcomes: `()`. The brackets indicate that the function block is *called*, which means that the implementation part of a function block is executed.

In order to illustrate the differences, let me make an example function block to show the differences.

### Example

Here I define a function block with a single input `Increment` and a single output `Count`. Every time the function block is called it will run the code in the implementation part. The implementation part will increment the current `Count` by `Increment`.

```
FUNCTION BLOCK FB_Counter 
VAR_INPUT
    Increment : UINT := 1;
END_VAR
VAR_OUTPUT
    Count : UINT := 0;
END_VAR

// Implementation part
Count := Count + Increment;
```

Let me make an instance `counter` of this function block in a program `Runner`, so we can see what happens when we call it.

```
PROGRAM Runner
VAR
    counter : FB_Counter;
END_VAR

counter(); // Count is set to 1 since the function block implementation is called
counter.Increment := 2; // Increment is set to 2, Count is still at 1 since the implementation of the function block is not called.
counter(); // Count is set to 3 since the implementation of the function block is now executed
counter(Increment:=1); // Increment is set back to 1 and the function block is called again, increasing the Count to 4.
```

If you step through the above code by using a break point you can see what happens at every step of the way.